# How to determine when x or y variable in linear regression diverges?

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am building a trading algorithm for someone else.

I am running linear regression on two columns of a dataframe. Volume and Price.

df:

```
   Volume     Price
0  12.952941  8.534815
1  12.972921  8.544813
```

This is how I am running linear regression

```
from scipy.stats import linregress

lr = linregress( df['Volume'],df['Price'])
```

One of requirements is to determine when Volume has diverged from Price or gone Up while price has gone down.

Is there any way to do this? I am not sure how to determine this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you expect `Volume` and `Price` to have a linear relationship? Have you tried plotting them?

Comment: Yes I do expect them to have a linear relationship. Have not plotted not them. Not sure how to plot price, volune and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [correlations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_coefficient) to do what you described.

Summarizing, correlations are used to describe the relationship between two variables such as volume and price in your question. So, whenever you correlate variables, a number between -1 and +1 is returned.

In general, if you have a positive correlation between the variables (usually > 0.6), you say that when the volume increases, the price also increases. On the other hand, a negative correlation (precisely a value close to -1), when a variable increases, the other decreases.

Usually, whenever you find a correlation close to zero, you can say that there is a weak correlation or no correlation.

Besides, there are rules to apply correlations. In general, when you have a Non-Gaussian distribution, you should use the Spearman correlation. Having a Gaussian distribution, you can use the Pearson correlation. To discover if your distribution is Gaussian or not you can use Kolmogorov–Smirnov test or Shapiro–Wilk test.

There is also another detail. When calculating the correlations, you have to verify the [p-value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value)  which quantifies the probability of being valid your correlation. Usually, a p-value < 0.05 is commonly acceptable. Otherwise, you can not conclude anything about your correlation result.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. This question maybe extremely dumb, but if correlation = -0.6, How do I tell which variable is going up or down?

Comment: I don't think that your question is dumb. Using solely correlations you will not be able to determine which variable is going up or down. Correlations will just describe the relationship between them. But, whenever you find a negative correlation, you can determine the trend estimation of each variable. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048571/python-finding-a-trend-in-a-set-of-numbers

Comment: Thank you very much @Thiago Procaci, this is exactly what I was looking for.