# Each element in list at least equal to the previous one

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

A list of monthly sales until November, I want to know if the sales trend is upward.

Definition of upward: each monthly sales is greater or at least equal to previous month's.

[image]

This question is similar to [Python: Finding a trend in a set of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048571/python-finding-a-trend-in-a-set-of-numbers), but much simpler - only looking the list of numbers.

What I have now is, to check them one by one (in a list). If one month satisfies the condition, it adds an "ok" to a new list. When total number of "ok" equals to 10. The original list of numbers are upward.

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame([['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov'],
[278,342,476,500,559,594,687,739,917,940,982]]).T
df_a.columns = ["Month",  "Sales"]

sales_a = df_a['Sales'].tolist()
ok_a = []

for num, a in enumerate(sales_a):
    if sales_a[num] >= sales_a[num-1]:
        ok_a.append("ok")

if ok_a.count("ok") == 10:
    print ("df_a is uptrend.")
```

What's the smarter way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Simple way would be to check `if(sales_a == sorted(sales_a)`, but at the cost of performance by a `log` factor.

Comment: @Raj, would you consider to post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandas Series has attribute  [`is_monotonic`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic.html)  to check on monotonic increasing. Don't need to sort or do anything fancy.

```
print(df_a.Sales.is_monotonic)

Out[94]: True

if df_a.Sales.is_monotonic:
    print('df_a is uptrend')

Output:
df_a is uptrend
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do as below

```
if df_a['Sales'].diff().fillna(0).ge(0).all():
    print ("df_a is uptrend.")
else:
    print ("df_a is NOT a uptrend.")
```

Comment: thank you! hope you don't mind I choose another shorter as answer. :)

Comment: No problem. With this answer, you don't have to create a list `sales_a`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `diff` and `period` method on pandas

```py
df_a['Sales_diff'] = df_a['Sales'].diff(periods=1)
df_a['OK'] = df_a['Sales_diff'] >= 0
df_a
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to check

```
if(sales_a == sorted(sales_a)):
    print("uptrend")
```

At the cost of increase in final complexity by a `log` factor.

Comment: would you mind I switch to another even shorter answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure that answer deserves it.